# Second JPanel covers the first one

Tags: java, swing

I am a beginner with programming and I have been struggling with the following problem for some time.

I have a list of `BufferedImage`s (`this.docList`). At the moment I am trying to 
put the images onto a `JPanel` and put that panel inside a `JScrollPane`.

If I have more than one image, the second image seems to cover the first one.
With the following code I make and send the `ScrollPane` to the  method `getPanel` which, when it is finished returns a `JPanel` containing the `ScrollPane` which contains the `Panel`(s) containing the `BufferedImage`s. Which are then added to the `JFrame`.

```
public void processView(SecondaryProcessPanel secondary){
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JScrollPane imageHolder = new JScrollPane();
    //imageHolder.setLayout(new BoxLayout(imageHolder BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JScrollPane panelBack = secondary.getPanel(imageHolder);
    panelBack.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,800));
    this.add(panelBack, 0);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600, 800);
    this.pack();

}
```

The method `getPanel` goes through the list of `BufferedImage`s. When it has finished the `JPanel` that this class is extended from is added to the `JScrollPane` and sent back to the `processView` method.

```
public JScrollPane getPanel(JScrollPane imageHolder) {      
    for (int j = 0; j< this.docList.size(); j++){
        image = this.docList.get(j);               
    }
    imageHolder = new JScrollPane(this);    

    return imageHolder;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0,0, null);
}
```

What ever way around I put it all I can get back from a list of two images is the second image.

Any help greatly appreciated.

After your kind answers I have changed my code back to what I had originally!

```
 public void processView(SecondaryProcessPanel secondary){
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for (int i = 0; i < this.docList.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("i = " + i);
        JScrollPane imageHolder = new JScrollPane();

        JScrollPane panelBack = secondary.getPanel(this.docList.get(i), imageHolder);
        panelBack.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,800));
        this.add(panelBack, i);
        }


    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600, 800);
    this.pack();

}

 public JScrollPane getPanel(BufferedImage image, JScrollPane imageHolder){

        this.image = image;


        imageHolder = new JScrollPane(this);    

    return imageHolder;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){


        g.drawImage(image, 0,0, null);
        }
```

My problem remains that if the docList ArrayList contains more than one BufferedImage then I only get output from the second image.

Comment: I think `image = this.docList.get(j);` is the problem, When the for-loop has finished `image` will always be the last `BufferedImage` inside `docList`. But to be sure a [mcve] would help very much. (I'm not sure if you posted all the code of your for-loop)

Comment: If this is solved, please [choose and accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signify that this is solved. You also get 2 reputation points for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is the fact that you're violating the painting process...

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0,0, null);
}
```

First of all, assuming that you're extending from a `JPanel`, you should be overriding the `paintComponent` method instead, second of all, you should be calling the methods `super` method

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0,0, this);
}
```

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing.

Second is, WHY?  `JLabel` can display an image just fine.  Have a look at [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details...

And finally...

```
public void processView(SecondaryProcessPanel secondary){
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    for (int i = 0; i < this.docList.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        JScrollPane imageHolder = new JScrollPane();

        JScrollPane panelBack = secondary.getPanel(this.docList.get(i), imageHolder);
        panelBack.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,800));
        this.add(panelBack, i);
    }


    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600, 800);
    this.pack();

}

public JScrollPane getPanel(BufferedImage image, JScrollPane imageHolder){

    this.image = image;
    imageHolder = new JScrollPane(this);    

    return imageHolder;
}
```

This all just looks very suspicious, it look like you're trying to add the same instance of a component to multiple `JScrollPane`'s, assigning a different image to the single instance each time...

So, this basically will remove the instance of the component from it's previous parent and then add it to the new container (`JScrollPane`) and supply a new instance of a `BufferedImage` for it to draw, basically ignoring every that came before it.

In the future, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

So, what you'll end up with is a lot of empty `JScrollPane`s, but with one which is displaying the last image in the list...

Comment: thank you for your help. .                                             The reason I wanted to do it this way is that I wanted to change the image once it has opened, But I will look at JLabels as you suggest,

Comment: thank you for your help. .                                                                        The reason I wanted to do it this way is that I wanted to change the image once it has opened, But I will look at JLabels as you suggest,     The problem I am having is exactly as you describe, I will now look again thank you. My apologies for not making my code clearer, I was trying to make my problem clear, I will know better next time.

Answer (score 0):

This takes the last image on the list - I dont understand what logic you are trying to implement but keeping the last image only is what it does - maybe you want to paint each image (you have a box layout add them there vertically) as it is being read

```
    for (int j = 0; j< this.docList.size(); j++){
                image = this.docList.get(j);

    }
```

--

My suggestion is as follows

```
GridLayout gr=new GridLayout(0, 6);
gr.setRows(0); gr.setColumns(6);
JPanel cpanel=new JPanel();
cpanel.setLayout(gr);
 for (int j = 0; j< this.docList.size(); j++){
    image = this.docList.get(j);
            JLabel jl=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
  cpanel.add(jl);
}
this.add(cpanel); // assuming 'this' is the scrollpane you want
```

and delete the paint method

Comment: Thank you I can see what you are saying. I altered the code just before posting but your comments and my silly mistake have given me some clarity. I think that one of the problems I have is getting over the idea that you can not just 'add' an image to a JPanel. Thank you for your answers.